# Writing data from one dataframe to a new column of another in R

Tags: r, for-loop, dataframe

I have two data frames in R. `data`, a frame with monthly sales per department in a store, looks like this:

[image: dataframe named data]

While `averages`, a frame with the average sales over all months per department, looks like this:

[image: dataframe named averages]

What I'd like to do is add a column to `data` containing the average sales (column 3 of `averages`) for each department. So whereas now I have an `avg` column with all zeroes, I'd like it to contain the overall average sales for whatever department is listed in that row. This is the code I have now:

```
for(j in 1:nrow(avgs)){
  for(i in 1:nrow(data)){
    if(identical(data[i,4], averages[j,1])){
      gd[i,10] <- avgs[j,3] } } }
```

After running the loop, the `avg` column in `data` is still all zeroes, which makes me think that `if(identical(data[i,4], averages[j,1]))` is always evaluating to `FALSE`... But why would this be? How can I troubleshoot this issue / is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Do not post your data as an image, please learn how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610)

Comment: @ProcrastinatusMaximus Now that I have the answer I see how it's related to the other question. Since I didn't know the name of the function was merge the other thread didn't come up in my searches, and I didn't really have enough of a mathematical understanding at the time of what I was trying to accomplish to think of it in terms of the join. ^.^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you looking for `merge` function?

```
merge(x = data, y = avgs, by = "departmentName", all.x=TRUE)
```

Comment: for some reason I'm getting a stack error when I try this method: `Error: C stack usage  19925264 is too close to the limit`. The dataframes are not huge so I don't know why that would be. Sorry, my fat fingers hit enter too soon

Comment: I believe this error is because of the deep recursion of the previous code and if you try any other could, you would see exact same error. Isn't it true? if you, perhaps you want to restart r. and please  post the data instead of the image to allow people reproduce your example

Comment: Right on the head about the restart. Ran perfect after that. Thank you!

Answer (score -2):

I would use dplyr by doing:

```
dplyr::full_join(data, averages, by = "departmentName")
```

The great thing about dplyr (besides being fast) is that it has a very simple syntax. Moreover, if your two tables have variables with different names, that can also be specified. Imagine you have data_departmentName in table data and avgs_departmentName in the table averages:

```
dplyr::full_join(data, averages, by = c("data_departmentName" = "averages_departmentName"))
```

And then I would filter the dataset if you only want a specific column from the second dataset. If you know your data is ordered and has the same lenght, then you could just add it like:

```
data$avgs <- averages$avgs
```

But I'd rather join first then filter.